# if statement with multiple conditions instead of using AND

Tags: c#

I been searching for some information about if statements with multiple conditions but haven't found something that corresponds to myquestion.

I was wondering if you could write:

```
int n = 3
if (3 < n < 20)
{
   //do something..
}
```

rather than doing:

```
if (n > 3 && n < 20)
{
   //do something..
}
```

The first statement doesn't work for me which i think it should, because it's plain simple.

Maybe someone can give me the correct syntax for doing so or maybe it's just impossible at all and i just have to go with the AND.

Comment: No, you need to use the second syntax, the first version won't work.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: okay, thanks for confirming this.

Comment: @Malling for this kind of confirmation your compiler is even faster than SO! ;)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti To be fair though, the reason why it doesn't work is slightly more obscure.

Comment: "i think it should, because it's plain simple"  What makes you think so? A programming-language doesn´t neccessarily fit a common syntax which you may think of a math-background. All languages have their own yntax which you have to follow. `3  <  n < 20` durely does *not* fit any of those syntax-rules.

Comment: @Sayse It complains about the first < operator cannot be applied to operands of type bool and int

Comment: @DavidG is it?!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti For a beginner yes.

Comment: @HimBromBeere i know i know that it can mean alot of things when a language has to compile it, but i just used to write it like this in most math programs so i thought that maybe C# could understand it too :)

Comment: @DavidG fairly true!

Comment: And now you know that it doesn´t work this way. So what is this question actually about?

Comment: @Malling if you were seeking for a "why" then I definitely have to reverse my downvote. It's not a bad question per-se. BTW some other (non-math) languages allow you to write it that way (Python, for example) but the reason behind it works might be pretty different in each language.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti it was actually a "why" question because i can't get it to work and didn't understand why :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To explain why it's invalid:

```
if (3 < n < 20)
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
if ((3 < n) < 20)
```

Now `3 < n`'s outcome would be a bool.

So basically you'll get:

```
if (true/false < 20)
```

Which is not valid in C#.

Comment: Oh yea thats explains the error i get saying it cannot convert from bool to int.
Thankyou for your explanation!

Comment: I mark it as a solution because it explains why i can't do that!

Comment: It is invalid because the language designers didn't allow the syntax in the question. They **could** have allowed it if they wanted to.

Comment: Hi @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: that's what I meant to say by explicitly stating that it's a C# thing: "*which is not valid in C#*". I agree that my answer is subject for a good debate, but my main intention here was to let OP see "why", (for now,) it's invalid, explain the error and mainly so he/she can spot similar occurrences in the future. Nevertheless, you are right, it is a designers choice and many other languages would accept this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Stefan's answer explains why it's impossible.
But here is a workaround, if you don't want to write that pesky `&&` explicit conditions every time - you can create an extension method:

```
public static class IComparableExtensions
{
    public static bool Between<T>(this T self, T low, T high) where T : IComparable
    {
        return self.CompareTo(low) > 0 && self.CompareTo(high) < 0;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int n = 5;
if(n.Between(3, 20))
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Please note, however, that this might be confusing - since `Between` doesn't specify if the compare is inclusive, exclusive, or inclusive in only one direction - so if you compare, say, `20.Between(10, 20)` - should it return true or false?

A better approach would require adding another variable to the method, to indicate that:

```
[Flags]
public enum CompareMode
{
    Exclusive = 0,
    IncludeLow = 1,
    IncludeHigh = 2,
    Inclusive = IncludeLow | IncludeHigh
}

public static class IComparableExtensions
{
    public static bool Between<T>(this T self, T low, T high, CompareMode mode) where T : IComparable
    {
        var compareLow = (mode & CompareMode.IncludeLow) == CompareMode.IncludeLow ? 0 : 1;
        var compareHigh = (mode & CompareMode.IncludeHigh) == CompareMode.IncludeHigh ? 0 : -1;
        return self.CompareTo(low) >= compareLow && self.CompareTo(high) <= compareHigh;
    }
}
```

Now you use it like this:

```
if(n.Between(3, 20, CompareMode.Exclusive))
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/BJT88701)

This way, another person reading this code (or even you, 6 months from now) will know immediately, without having to look inside the `Between` extension method, if between is inclusive, exclusive, or whatever.

Comment: are't you calling a method to do the same thing which OP wasn't wanting to do in first place ?

Comment: @Amit Yes, but the point of the extension method is to eliminate the need to write the explicit condition every time. It's just a shortcut...

Comment: @Amit I've edited my answer to better explain that. Thanks to your comments, my answer is better now, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not possible what you want to do.

but in your logic if you want to perform single liner logic you can use ternary operator.

for eg. you need to assign value of n to variblae `result` else it should be 0 as default.

```
int result = n > 3 ? (n < 20 ? n : 0) : 0
```

it is equivalent to

```
int result = 0;
if (n > 3 && n < 20)
{
   result = n;
}
```